# Trying to output from one table by checking does rows from second equals to first

Tags: php, mysql

What am I doing wrong here?

```
    "SELECT stats.fromid, stats.fromname, stats.text, stats.profilepic, friendslist.myid, friendslist.friendid 
FROM stats INNER JOIN friendslist 
ON ((stats.fromid=friendslist.myid AND friendslist.friendid='$logger') OR (stats.fromid=friendslist.friendid AND friendslist.myid='$logger') OR stats.fromid='$logger')  ORDER BY stats.id DESC"
```

Why does my `OR stats.fromid='$logger'` output duplicated rows from database ? For others everything is normal but for that one is duplicated is there option to LIMIT 1 output per id?

Thanks

Comment: Not enough data, why do you think it's broken? Do you have SQL error or just no results? You sure you're injecting your $logger variable fine? What do you see when you dump your actual end query?

Comment: if both tables have an *id* column, then the `order by` will produce an error. Better prefix it with table name.

Comment: What's the error? Can you input more detail about $logger, or columns of stats/friendslist tables?

Comment: @trincot oh didnt know that I will try it

Comment: I found solution but when I try to output my statuses as well I get duplicate I edited question...

Comment: now without code change its tripled

Comment: I found solution again by adding SELECT * FROM stats WHERE fromid='$logger' OR EXISTS(ALL OTHER CODE) and remove ORDER BY stats.id and add on the end of first ORDER BY id DESC and it work perfect